# How to parallelise a while loop that has iterations on a matrix with OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelise the while loop of this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define n 100

float max_dif(float w_new[n][n], float w[n][n]);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float w[n][n],w_new[n][n]={0},max=100;

#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            w[i][j]=75;
        }
    }

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w[0][i]=0;
        w[n-1][i]=100;
        w[i][0]=100;
        w[i][n-1]=100;

        w_new[0][i]=0;
        w_new[n-1][i]=100;
        w_new[i][0]=100;
        w_new[i][n-1]=100;
    }

    w[0][n-1]=100;
    w_new[0][n-1]=100;

    int counter=0;

    while(max > 0.0001)
    {   
        for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < n-1; j++)
            {
                w_new[i][j]=(float)((w[i+1][j]+w[i-1][j]+w[i][j+1]+w[i][j-1])/4);
            }
        }
        max = max_dif(w_new,w);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                w[i][j]=w_new[i][j];
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    printf("Counter is: %d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}

float max_dif(float w_new[n][n], float w[n][n])
{
    int i,j;
    float max=0;
    for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            if (max < fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]))
                max = fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I was thinking of the basic parallel for construct inside the while, but my counter variable is expected to be around 5000. So I would like that to be in parallel. But I need w_new to copy back to w so I can calculate the next iteration of w_new. So I don't think tasks or sections would work as I would need one w for the other.

Comment: Do you plan to change `n` and use a bigger value? While it is possible to parallelize *efficiently* the code, this far from being not easy with `n=100`. It might be better to use stencil libraries that do that very efficiently (see [Pochoir](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/pochoir_spaa11.pdf) for example).

Comment: It's for an assignment, so maybe. It's to give a taste on how to use openmp. To correctly think and know where and how constructs and clauses apply. I was just wondering if there was a better way of parallelising a while loop, like tasks. But as I need one result for the next step it has to be with just pragma omp for

Comment: Ok. I think the solution provided by @dreamcrash is clearly enough for an assignment. Note that this is possible to parallelize the while loop more efficiently using the method provided in the research paper. It uses trapezoidal space-time tiles to reduce the number of synchronizations and improve data locality. However, it is also hard to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallelizing directly the  `while(max > 0.0001)` will be *complicated* with OpenMP and probably not that performant as well. In OpenMP you have two main ways of parallelizing code either using loop-based or task-based parallelism. The latter is not suitable for the current code and the former cannot be applied to a *loop* that at compile-time is not possible to determined the number of iterations performed by that loop.

However, you can parallelize the computation performed inside the *while* instead, for instance:

```
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
      #pragma omp for
      for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++){
            w_new[i][j]=(float)((w[i+1][j]+w[i-1][j]+w[i][j+1]+w[i][j-1])/4);
        }
      }
```

the `max_dif` is definitely a good candidate for parallelization as well:

```
#pragma omp for reduction(max: max)
for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++){
        if (max < fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]))
            max = fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]);
    }
}
```

and finally the last loop inside the *while*:

```
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            w[i][j]=w_new[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, to apply this approach you will have to inline the function `max_dif` because the variable to be used in the reduction clause has to be *shared*, and since `max` is allocated inside the parallel region it will be private to each thread. Using the `shared` clause in `#pragma omp for` is not allowed.

**Full example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define n 100
int main()
{
    float w[n][n],w_new[n][n]={0},max=100;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            w[i][j]=75;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        w[0][i]=0;
        w[n-1][i]=100;
        w[i][0]=100;
        w[i][n-1]=100;

        w_new[0][i]=0;
        w_new[n-1][i]=100;
        w_new[i][0]=100;
        w_new[i][n-1]=100;
    }

    w[0][n-1]=100;
    w_new[0][n-1]=100;

    int counter=0;

    while(max > 0.0001){   
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
          max = 0;
          #pragma omp for    
          for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
             for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++)
                w_new[i][j]=(float)((w[i+1][j]+w[i-1][j]+w[i][j+1]+w[i][j-1])/4);
        
          #pragma omp for reduction(max: max)
          for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
             for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++){
               if (max < fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]))
                  max = fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]);
             }
          }       
          #pragma omp for nowait
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                 w[i][j]=w_new[i][j];
      }
      counter++;
    }

    printf("Counter is: %d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Counter is: 4894
```

> I was thinking of the basic parallel for construct inside the while,
> but my counter variable is expected to be around 5000. So I would like
> that to be in parallel.

That is possible but will require some changes. I explain them in the code. Actually we can use a single parallel region for the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define n 100

int main()
{
   float w[n][n],w_new[n][n]={0},max=100;
   int counter = 0;
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp for
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
             w[i][j]=75;

      #pragma omp for
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        w[0][i]=0;
        w[n-1][i]=100;
        w[i][0]=100;
        w[i][n-1]=100;

        w_new[0][i]=0;
        w_new[n-1][i]=100;
        w_new[i][0]=100;
        w_new[i][n-1]=100;
     }

     w[0][n-1]=100;
     w_new[0][n-1]=100;

     
    while(max > 0.0001){
       // We need this barrier to ensure that we don't have a
       // race condition between the master updating max to zero
       // and the other threads reading max > 0.0001 
       #pragma omp barrier
       #pragma omp master
       #pragma omp atomic write
        max = 0;
       #pragma omp barrier
       
        #pragma omp for reduction(max:max)
        for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
           for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++){
               w_new[i][j]=(float)((w[i+1][j]+w[i-1][j]+w[i][j+1]+w[i][j-1])/4);
               if (max < fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]))
                   max = fabs(w_new[i][j]-w[i][j]);
           }
        }      
          
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
               w[i][j]=w_new[i][j];
          
        #pragma omp master
        counter++;
     } 
   }
   printf("Counter is: %d\n", counter);
   return 0;
}
```

I tested superficially, and for 4 cores this version had a speedup of `2.8x` for an input of 1000 nothing too great. Further improvements can be done by trying to vectorize parts of it.